# Looking to auto increment in a sciprt

Tags: bash, specifications

I need to increment the package version in the spec file for automating RPM builds.

```
FILE=somefile1.spec
OLD=$(grep "packageversion 2.64" "$FILE" | awk {'print $3'})
NEW=$(($OLD | bc -l))
echo $NEW
```

Returns:

```
change_spec: line 11: 2.64 | bc -l: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error  token is ".64 | bc -l")
```

I am open to suggestions, as you can see, my script writing abilities are nil.

Comment: `$((...))` is arithmetic evaluation not process substitution. Did you mean `$(...)` there? Though how the contents of `$OLD` would already be an expression there I'm not sure (but I don't know what your spec file has in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $OLD equals .64, then you can do:

```
NEW=$((${OLD:1} + 1))
```

Just `echo $OLD` before to see its content (and report it here!).

`${OLD:1}` simply do a substring, as described here: [Substring Extraction](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTREXTR01).

Comment: Thank both of you for your help. NoData's solution worked for me.